# How to create a Material UI Table with the exact same height as its parent and that allows scrolling on the TableBody if there are too many rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Good evening.

I'm trying to create a table that has the exact same height as it's parent, which itself shares the page with a search bar at the top, of variable height, totaling together 100vh.

The TableBody would, then, grow as much as it can, only leaving some space for the TableHeader and TableFooter.

However, I cannot manage to make the TableBody stop increasing the parent's height when there are too many rows. The height of the columns also get increased, instead of remaining constant.

How could I force the TableBody to fit to the parent's size and allow the user to scroll through its contents, also without deforming the size of the rows?

Comment: did you try overflow: hidden in a parent class with css ?

Comment: Yes but, unfortunately, the body just increases the size of the parent all the same.

Comment: possibility to fix a height of parent div in pixel ? ex: .parent {height: 500px;overflow:hidden} .child{height: 100%; overflow:auto}

Comment: No, the height of the parent must be dynamic. The goal is for the table to take all of the height of the page, except for the search bar.